# Find the Subextensions of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt2, \sqrt3, \sqrt5)/\Bbb Q$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

As an exercise for myself I want to find the subextensions of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt2, \sqrt3, \sqrt5)/\Bbb Q$.

I know that it has Galois group $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$x$\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$x$\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$, and this has 8 subgroups (since $2^3=8$).

This means that $\Bbb Q(\sqrt2, \sqrt3, \sqrt5)/\Bbb Q$ must have exactly 8 extensions, but I find more, so I must assume that some are equivalent.  The possibilities I consider are:

$\Bbb Q$, $\Bbb Q(\sqrt2)$, $\Bbb Q(\sqrt3)$,$\Bbb Q(\sqrt5)$, $\Bbb Q(\sqrt6)$, $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{10})$, $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{15})$, $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{30})$, $\Bbb Q(\sqrt2, \sqrt3)$, $\Bbb Q(\sqrt2, \sqrt5)$, $\Bbb Q(\sqrt3, \sqrt5)$, which makes 11 different subfields.  I assume I have to show that some fields are equivalent, but how would one approach that?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why would it have $8$ subgroups ?

Comment: Your observation that $2^3=8$ does not imply that there are $8$ subgroups...

Comment: There are *7* 1-dimensional subgroups, a trivial subgroup, and the full subgroup. Already that's more than 8...

Comment: I know something is wrong, evidently.  I thought there was 8 subgroups because I can think of the Galois group as $<(x,y,z)>$, where each element is either $0$ or $1$.  This generates the Galois group.  Then I have 2 possibilities for each "coordinate", so then I have $2^3$ "elements", yes this doesn't make much sense does I realize as I type it.

Comment: @Jeff: You are on the right track, though: having '1's in your vector representation corresponds to not fixing one of the roots.

Comment: Since there are seven subgroups of order $2$, there ought to be seven subgroups of index $2$ as well.

Comment: To find all the subgroups of the Galois group, say G, the most "visible" way is to view G as a 3- dimensional vector space over the field Z/2Z.  The strict non trivial subgroups are subspaces of dimension 1 or 2. The 1-dim. subspaces are "lines", each containing only two non null vectors , so their determination amounts to the determination of the non null vectors of G. The 2-dim. spaces are "(hyper)planes", which can be characterized as kernels of linear forms, so they can be determined by the "lines" of the dual space G* . To do all this, take the obvious basis of G and the dual basis of G*